# Can audio be triggered to play during phone lock

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, howler.js

I am making a web chat app and now I am in need of playing notification sounds as a new message arrives.

To begin with I am using [howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/) to play the sounds. In howler we can start playing a sound and then if we lock the screen or change browser tab focus it keeps playing. **But** it doesn't start playing the sound if the tab is opened and mobile screen is locked nor does it play if the user is on another tab with the app on another tab opened.

So basically my question is, **is it possible to start playing sound even when screen is locked or start playing the sound when user is on another tab?**

**app.js**

```
var notify_sound = new Howl({
    src: ['./assets/sounds/notify2.mp3'],
    volume: 1.0
});
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
if(type == "user"){
        if(userAddress == remoteAddress) {
            typing.html('').fadeOut('fast');
            messages.append('<li class="self"><p class="message">'+ obj.message + '</p><p class="time">' + time +'</p></li><p class="username_self">' + userAddress + '</p>');
        }
        else {
            typing.html('').fadeOut('fast');
            messages.append('<li class="other"><p class="message">'+ obj.message + '</p><p class="time">' + time +'</p></li><p class="username_other">' + userAddress + '</p>');

            notify_sound.play();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 audio and mobile don't really get along. Howler.js (If you're using 2.0) uses a workaround to get audio to 'autoplay' at all by attaching an event handler to the first touch event that'll trigger playback. If the view isn't active, there won't be a touch event (even a simulated one) to trigger playback.

From the docs:

> **Mobile Playback**
>
> By default, audio on iOS, Android, etc is locked until a sound is
>   played within a user interaction, and then it plays normally the rest
>   of the page session (Apple documentation). The default behavior of
>   howler.js is to attempt to silently unlock audio playback by playing
>   an empty buffer on the first touchend event. This behavior can be
>   disabled by calling:
>
> `Howler.mobileAutoEnable = false;`

If there's no initial interaction, there's not much you can do.

Comment: so ultimately it is conclusive that during a screen lock sound wont be played.?

Comment: You might be able to hack around it with a continuously playing sprite. I haven't tested this approach though.

Comment: But playing it continuously would take up resources of the client if he is on a slow connection.

Comment: Wouldn't have much to do with the connection at playback time. I'm suggesting just like half a second of a looped silent mp3, just to keep a sound active. Alternatively, you could investigate using the Notification API which based on the User Agent will play a system sound. I don't know if you can customize the sound though. Note that this approach will require user-granted permissions.

Comment: Can you kindly show an example of what you said about customizing sound? Permission are not a matter.

Comment: [It looks like there's no support for custom sound.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API)

Comment: Bad luck. I really don't know what to do.